# Differentiate ModelAdmin media for add/change pages in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, media, modeladmin

To encapsulate customized functionalities in Django admin I'm providing a custom [`ModelAdmin` class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) that actually looks like this:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```

I noted that `my_code.js` gets loaded both in add and change pages, but I need to load it only in the add page. Is it possible to do this (and how)?

Comment: I think (but might be wrong) this is not possible via `class Media`. If you overwrite the specific admin templates you can achieve this behavior though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the list of JavaScript files to include is generated and assigned by the `media` context variable provided from the admin application's view function, which you can't easily override.  But here's one not-so-elegant solution:

View source on the admin add page for your current model and copy the script tags that import the JavaScript files starting at line 14 (I'm using Django 1.2).  You'll see where to paste them in the code fragment below.

Create your own custom `change_form.html` template in your `templates/admin/my_app/article` directory, and place the following contents in the file:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
{% url admin:jsi18n as jsi18nurl %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ jsi18nurl|default:"../../../jsi18n/" }}"></script>
{% if add %}
{{ media }}
{% else %}
<!-- originally generated script tags: may differ depending on your model's fields -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<!-- end originally generated script tags -->
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Note that if you add a date field, for example, to your model, the field won't work properly on the change form when you edit a record, because a needed `calendar.js` file won't be called in.  You'd have to add it manually if you made such a change.

One alternative to go further with this and restore the lost dynamicness would be to create a template filter that you could pass the `media` variable into and use a regex, for example, to strip out the unwanted script tag.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how StackOverflow likes digging up old posts, but I found this doing research for my own problem and found a slightly more elegant solution than the accepted answer. You can over-ride the`render_change_form` method to update the `context['media']` definition. Sample for this question:

```
def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
    if add:
        if context.has_key('media'):
            old_media = context['media']
        else:
            old_media = forms.Media()
        context.update({'media': old_media+forms.Media(js=("js/SPD_media_admin.js",)) })
    return super(ArticleAdmin,self).render_change_form(request=request, context=context, add=add, change=change, form_url=form_url, obj=obj)
```

This works with Django 1.4. Interested readers may need to adjust the `args` and `kwargs` to match the method specifications. `context` is not usually passed to this method as a `kwarg` otherwise I think it could have been edited without explicitly listing the `args`. Hope this is helpful to the OP or posterity.